# My worker node status is Ready,SchedulingDisabled

Tags: kubernetes

I have kubernetes cluster and every thing work fine. after some times I drain my worker node and reset it and join it again to master but

```
#kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS                     ROLES    AGE    VERSION
ubuntu    Ready                      master   159m   v1.14.0
ubuntu1   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   <none>   125m   v1.14.0
ubuntu2   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   <none>   96m    v1.14.0
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I fixed it using:

```
kubectl uncordon <node-name>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: In my case the answer also contained the explanation basically, because this is how I've found out that how to tell if a node is cordoned (if the status is "SchedulingDisabled" ). It was a somewhat the other way around. But sure, explaining what 'cordon' means wouldn't have hurt.

Comment: I tried the uncordon but after a few seconds it returns to SchedulingDisabled state. How can I check what it prevents it from completing the uncordon?

Answer (score 109):

To prevent a node from scheduling new pods use:

```
kubectl cordon <node-name>
```

Which will cause the node to be in the status: `Ready,SchedulingDisabled`.

To tell is to resume scheduling use:

```
kubectl uncordon <node-name>
```

More information about draining a node can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/). And manual node administration [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#manual-node-administration)

Comment: After running kubectl cordon <node-name>, I'm able to create new pods on the node.

Answer (score 5):

scheduling disabled represents that node got into maintenance mode , as you drained nodes of the pods which has prerequisite that the node must be in maintenance . check the spec of that nodes
`kubetcl get nodes node-name -o yaml`

```
 taints:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable
    timeAdded: "2022-06-29T13:05:11Z"
  unschedulable: true
```

so when you want it to be back to schedulable state you will have to put node out of maintenance means uncordon it

```
kubectl uncordon <node-name>
```

I know it's similar to above answers but one should know what's happening behind the scenes .

Answer (score 0):

For Openshift (see [oc administrator commands](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/cli_reference/openshift_cli/administrator-cli-commands.html#oc-adm-uncordon)) you can use: `oc adm uncordon <node-name>`

Here's a quick way to reschedule all nodes:

```
oc get nodes --no-headers | awk '{print $1}' | xargs oc adm uncordon
```